# My android app has crashed if I using APK from 'app\build\outputs'

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, apk

I launched and debugging my application successfully by Android Studio via USB.
But if I copied APK from `\app\build\outputs\apk` the application crashed after installation.

What's difference between installed APK and launched via Android Studio?
How to fix trouble?

Comment: did you copy or cut ? you have to clean project if you cut

Comment: Copied of course. But no difference for my device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enable multidex

```
defaultConfig {
...
             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
```

try also Disable InstaRun

Go to Preferences and find the Instant Run option under Build, Execution, Deployment. Uncheck the check boxes to disable instant run

clean and delete debug.apk.

and try `Build>BuildAPK` again

Hope it works. . if stills fail then you should make release apk instead.

Comment: It helps. I disabled InstaRun and enabled multidex and rebuilt the project. But I still misunderstanded reason of crash.

Comment: Because of its limit executable file. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX file, known as a multidex configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what is causing your trouble but when I had my app installed on the system and didn't change the app for a signed one it'd crash.

So what I'd do is to make sure that the app is uninstalled from your phone and then build a signed APK to use.